the algebraic relation for distances of some points on the curved surface
The following sentences are from Weinberg's book on gravitation, where he says that we can use airline distances between four places on earth to tell earth surface is curved. The page number is 7.
Consider $N$ points in a plane. We can use one point as an origin of coordinates and draw an x-axis through a second point, so that the distances between the various points are described in terms of $(2N-3)$ coordinates, that is, the x-coordinates of the second point and the x-and y-coordinates of the remaining $(N-2)$ points. But there are $N(N-1)/2$ different distances between the N points, and thus for large engouh N these distances must be subject to M algebraic relations, where $M = N(N-1)/2-(2N-3)=(N-2)(N-3)/2$
I am having difficulty following his argument.

Why only draw an x-axis? What about the y-axis?
Why is the number of algebraic relations=number of distances-number of unknown coordinates?
Why does N need to be large enough?



Why only draw an x-axis? What about the y-axis?

This is in a plane. Once the $x$-axis is defined, the $y$-axis is defined as well: it is the rotation of the $x$-axis by 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

Why is the number of algebraic relations=number of distances-number of unknown coordinates?

Label the points $p_1$ thru $p_N$ with $d_{ij}$ being the distance between $p_i$ and $p_j$.
We can choose an arbitrary $p_1$ and any positive value for $d_{12}$. There infinitely many points in that circle around $p_1$ that we can choose for $p_2$. However for every $p_i, i > 2$, the two distances $d_{1i}, d_{2i}$ determine the location of $p_i$ to be one of at most two possibilities. That is, these $2N-3$ choices of distances along with $N-2$ binary choices completely determine the locations of all the points, and therefore all the other $M = \frac{N(N+1)}2 - (2N-3)$ distances. Those are the $M$ algebraic relations.
This argument differs from the one Weinberg is suggesting, as it isn't coordinate-based, but it is equivalent, and I thought it easier to explain.

Why does N need to be large enough?

When $N=1$, you can't even define the coordinate system. When $N=2$ or $N=3$, you get $M=0$ - no algebraic relations between the distances. It is only when $N \ge 4$ that an algebraic relationship exists. (One that gives a different answer if it turns out we are actually on a large sphere and just thought it was a plane.)
